# Updating a nodejs image inside of a Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I am trying to update the node version that we are using inside the Dockerfile of my application. Currently it is set as v12.21.0. I would like to update it to v16.13.0 as that is the current node LTS version. Please see my dockerfile code below.

So I turned this:

```
FROM node:12.21.0-alpine as build

RUN apk --update add bash

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

FROM opsline/tools:alpine AS tools

FROM node:12.21.0-alpine

RUN apk --update --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=tools /usr/local/bin/chalk /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=tools /usr/local/bin/gosu /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build ./build
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/server ./server
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/package.json .
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/scripts/pre-start.js .

COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

To This:

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine as build

RUN apk --update add bash

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

FROM opsline/tools:alpine AS tools

FROM node:16.13.0-alpine

RUN apk --update --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=tools /usr/local/bin/chalk /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=tools /usr/local/bin/gosu /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build ./build
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/server ./server
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/package.json .
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/scripts/pre-start.js .

COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Is it true that all I would have to do is change the node version manually in the code and the rest should fall into place? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can check the current node LTS version here https://nodejs.org/en/ which is **16.14.2 LTS**. 

For future releases check here https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Comment: Does it work if you run it?  What problems are you running into when you change the version in the `FROM` line?

Answer (score 0):

Changing version will upgrade NodeJS if you are installing
but here your are using it as Base Image so you need to check whether such version is available in docker hub[image: Docker hub screenshot]
If it is there we can use but 16.13.0-alpine is not there So I think you need to change version number to any version available at https://hub.docker.com/_/node